# I'm doing some Python exercises and can't seem to get around this error

Tags: python

```
class Student:

     def get_name(self):
            """Return the name of current Student object."""
            return self.name
    
     def get_age(self):
            """Return the age of the current Student object."""
            return self.age
    
     def say_hello(self, message=None) -> None:
            if message is not None:
                print(f"{self.name} says: {message}")
            else:
                print(f"Hello, my name is {self.name}. Nice to meet you!")

if __name__ == '__main__':

        student = Student(name='Wes', age=10)
        name = student.get_name()
        age = student.get_age()
    
        student.say_hello()
    
        message = f"The student's name is {name}. Their age is {age}."
        student.say_hello(message)
```

I get this error:

```
File “student.py”, line 21, in <module> student = Student(name=‘Wes’, age=10) TypeError: Student() takes no arguments
```

when this is supposed to be the result:

```
Hello, my name is Wes. Nice to meet you!

Wes says: The student's name is Wes. Their age is 10.
```

Comment: And where do you think you defined arguments for creating a Student with? You have getter methods (not very Pythonic FYI) for attributes you never set anywhere.

Comment: The error is, `TypeError: Student() takes no arguments`, and that's because your `Student` class has no `__init__` method, so you cannot pass arguments when you instantiate the class (this method is also typically where you would *set* these various attributes).

Comment: If this is an exercise assigned by your instructor, didn't they teach about how to initialize instance attributes?

Comment: Getters and setters like `get_age()` and `get_name()` are common in languages like Java, but an antipattern in Python. Just access `age` and `name` directly. You can use the `property` decorator if you need to change implementation details later. If your exercises recommend writing getters, I suggest you find a better resource.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined Student class without a `def __init__` method required if you want to send arguments when initiating a new class instance. Add:

```
def __init__(self, name, age):
    self.name = name
    self.age = age
```

as a method at the top of your class definition.